# What does ' turned out' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I'd like to know What does ' turned out' mean? in this phrases

> this problem has widely studied by many of researchers and many geometric properties  have turned out to be useful to determine an upper bounded.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the phrasal verb *to turn out*.  [It means "to happen" or "to become known to happen in a particular way".](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/turn-out)

So in this sentence it means that *many geometric properties have become known to be...*

Comment: More specifically, "X turned out to be useful" means that it wasn't realised at the time that X would be useful, but it became apparent later.

Answer (score 0):

it means "it appeared...." or "we found out... "